# Catapult animation

Tags: animation, rigging, logic-bricks

[image]

Hi guys I'm totally new to game design, I managed to make a very simple catapult and it shoots and moves fine, the problem is when I turn the catapult to face another direction and tell it to fire it always wants to fire both from a fixed location on the map and to the right, it will even disconnect from the base of my catapult as shown in the picture above, how do I get it to stop doing that and only fire in the direction the object is looking at and to not leave the catapult base while firing?

Comment: FYI in blender you can Save Screenshot from the Window menu

Comment: Or use **Win+PrtScreen** to capture active menus too.

Comment: Hi. http://take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking better screenshots.

Comment: Have you got an active modifier in that model somewhere?  If so you have to pay attention to origin points when you're putting it together. Rotation and scaling of components in particular during construction can upset models when modifiers are at work. (not "applied") For trouble-free animation, hard mesh parts/components of a model are a lot easier to live with.